# What happens to my U.S. Social Security and pension if I retire in Germany?

Tags: united-states, retirement, germany, social-security

If I retire in Germany, can I receive my U.S. Social Security and pension there, and will it be taxed?

Comment: Taxed by the US, or by Germany?  But in general, yes, you can collect SS while living abroad.

Comment: There is an agreememt between the US and Germany with more specific regulations for these cases ([text](https://www.ssa.gov/international/Agreement_Texts/germ_agt.html)). This brochure by _Deutsche Rentenversicherung_ may be useful: https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/Allgemein/de/Inhalt/5_Services/03_broschueren_und_mehr/01_broschueren/02_international/weitere_abkommen_fremdsprachig/working_germany_usa.html

Comment: check on the expatriates site, there will be more info